# Are there any alternatives for 74LS__ chips?

Tags: integrated-circuit

A beginners electronics book tells me to get the following:
74LS92 counter chip, 74LS06 open-collector inverter chip, and 74LS27 triple-input NOR chip.

Now, this book is from a couple years back, and I see that these chips are quite expensive on eBay (I have to pay $6 for 2x the first one, e.g.)

So I'm wondering, are there any alternatives to these that would be cheaper/more readily available? How could I know this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more modern replacement for 74LS chips would be 74HCT chips. They have similar performance, the same I/O specs, but are implemented in CMOS instead of bipolar technology.

74HC chips are similar, except that they use CMOS I/O specs, which means that they are compatible with other CMOS (e.g., 4000-series) chips.

CMOS and TTL chips can talk to each other under most circumstances, but you need to pay a little more attention to the details.

Comment: Is there such a thing as an HCT92? Octopart doesn't find any such thing (but maybe there's a different pn for it). Depending what OP's book wants him to do, he might have a problem with newer families not including a lot of the MSI functions (divide-by-12 counter, bcd functions, or whatever) that were common in the earlier families.

Comment: Perhaps not. My 1987 "Samsung High Performance CMOS Logic Data Book" jumps straight from 74HCT86 to 74HCT107. In that case, you're either going to have to pay for the older chips, or re-engineer a functional equivalent. (... or find a more modern book. :-)

Comment: "which means that they are compatible with other CMOS (e.g., 4000-series) chips." Almost never. 4000-series chips generally have completely different pinouts, and their input voltage thresholds are not offset the way 74HCT levels are. As well, 74HCT is typically only speced for essentially 74LS supply voltages, while CD4000s have much wider ranges. Finally, CD4000 chips run at 5 volts are typically about 1/10 as fast as 74HC/HCT.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the compatibility comment is about *74HC*, not 74HCT. And they’re logic-level / threshold-level compatible with 4000 series. Nowhere it’s mentioned that they’re pin-compatible, although there certainly do exist 74HC IC’s that are pin compatible with 4000 series.

Comment: I declined a flag here. Point understood but it's hard to please everyone. Deleting comments selectively removes clarity and even imperfect material has educational value for those who care to follow the thread.

Answer (score 3):

Then, are you sure that eBay is the best source of these chips?

In our local store:
74LS92 €1.00
74LS06 €0.60

You should specify your location a bit. In Europe we use for example Farnell, but there are other good eshops as well.

Answer (score 3):

Checking Octopart.com, large distributors offer 74LS92 for ~$2.50 each. And 74LS27 for less than $1. These are reasonable prices when you are asking them to box and ship onesy-twosy parts. If you want to learn with discrete chips (which isn't a bad idea) these prices are fair.

If you're willing to skip building things out of individual gates, you can get a demo board with a CPLD or FPGA and jump straight to designing in Verilog or VHDL. You might pay more than $50 for the board, but you will be able to re-use it for many different types of projects. The main drawback will be you will miss the experience of building things with physical chips representing individual gates. Depending on your learning style, this could end up being no problem, or a major barrier to understanding.

Comment: Asking someone to jump into HDL when they're asking about building discrete logic is like telling someone to start building a fighter jet from a kit when all they want to learn is how to make paper airplanes... Technically you're right, they can do it but there is so much they will miss (and recommending an easily damaged FPGA is not something I'd recommend either).